# How do you push in Github Desktop

Tags: github-for-windows

Github Desktop version is Chocolate-Covered Yaks (3.3.4.0) 50415df.

There are a lot of tutorials and responses on here, but all of them talk about things like sync buttons.  There is no sync in this version.

The files have been committed.  Clicking on 'open this repository in explorer' shows all the correct files on the local computer, but they do not show up on the website.

Does anyone know how to push in the new version?

Comment: Pretty out of date if you're using choco, thought about installing the latest edition from https://desktop.github.com/?

Comment: Have you commited your changes in the GUI?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is the version that is installed on the computers at school.  I didn't realize it was not the latest until your response.  We're stuck using what they have on the machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I'm assuming you have cloned the repo you are working in. And you own the repo you are working in. Meaning you have full access to the repo and you can push and commit to the repo.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1RGE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Jrr.png)

You need to make changes to your local files, it would show up like so in the screenshot above.

Once you have changes you are satisfied with, write something in the summary box and "commit" to the branch you are working on.

After you commit, you should get a button on the top right saying "Push origin"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1RGE.png

If you don't see it, try pressing the pull button before you push.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have that version on my home computer and it all works just great, exactly as you suggest.